# How can I move the bezier handle (not vertexs) in Sketch?

Tags: sketch-app

I can't find the name of the things which stick out of vertex to show what angle and strength the bezier is going to curve coming out, so I'm calling them bezier handles.

Anyways, I keep getting vertexs that have none coming out, and sometimes dragging on the vertex adds them and other times it moves the vertex.  Is there some way I can specify what I want?  Like, hold some key to move a vertex, hold this other key to move the shape, and hold this other key to move bezier handles?

Comment: Sounds like you need to find a tutorial on how to use the Vector tool in Sketch.

Comment: I tend to prefer an internet where information is organized in Q&A form over long, drawn out, probably out of date, poor SEO tutorials.  If I find a decent tutorial, I'll put the answer here to help the next person.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vertexs in Sketch have four Bezier modes.  The modes are Straight, Mirrored, Assymetric, and Disconnected.

When a vertex is in "Straight" mode, no bezier handles are present.  Also, in "Straight" mode, there is the option to add a curved "Corner".  Because of this a curve may be present that is not editable the bezier handles.